# Getting string from Json Object

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to retrieve values from [json](/questions/tagged/json) but I keep getting the same error:

> org.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.JSONArray

I think this happens because distance is a object, so how can I retrieve distance and add it to the [hashmap](/questions/tagged/hashmap), below is JAVA and JSON code:

```
                        if (steps != null) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < steps.length(); j++) {
                                JSONObject singleStep = (JSONObject) steps.get(j);
                                HashMap<String, String> direcao = new HashMap<>();

                                JSONArray distance = (JSONArray) singleStep.get("distance");
                                if (distance != null) {
                                    JSONObject singleDistance = (JSONObject) distance.get(0);
                                    String dist = singleDistance.getString("text");
                                    direcao.put("textDi", dist);
                                }

                                JSONArray duration = (JSONArray) singleStep.get("duration");
                                if (duration != null) {
                                    JSONObject singleDuration = (JSONObject) duration.get(0);
                                    String dura = singleDuration.getString("text");
                                    direcao.put("textDu", dura);
                                }

                                String html = singleStep.getString("html_instructions");
                                direcao.put("html_instructions2", html);
                                listaDirecoes.add(direcao);

                            }
                        }
```

JSON

```
steps: [
   {
      distance: {
         text: "0,3 km",
         value: 342
      },
      duration: {},
      end_location: {},
      html_instructions: "Siga <b>sul</b> em direção a <b>N3</b>",
      polyline: {},
      start_location: {},
      travel_mode: "DRIVING"
   },
   {},
```

Comment: { } means JSONObject and [ ] means JSONArray, and in your response distance is JSONObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

distance is not an array it is Json object. use this

```
   JSONObject distance = singleStep.getJSONObject("distance");
```

Answer (score 1):

JSONArray distance = (JSONArray) singleStep.get("distance"); here is problem instaed of JSONArray use JSONObject there.use

JSONObject distance = singleStep.getJSONObject("distance");

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray distance = (JSONArray) singleStep.get("distance");
JSONArray distance = (JSONArray) singleStep.get("duration");
```

Here you have define it as **JSONArray** but in Response its **JSONObject**.

Answer (score 0):

distance is a JSONObject, not an JSONArray. Try this:

```
JSONObject distance = (JSONObject) singleStep.getJSONObject("distance");
                            if (distance != null) {
                                String dist = distance.getString("text");
                                direcao.put("textDi", dist);
                            }
```